# Why isn't a uniform distribution on a bounded set subgaussian?

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure

On High Dimensional Probability, by Vershynin, there is an exercise that asks to prove that the uniform distribution on the $l_1$ ball of radius $n$, $X \sim {Unif} \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_1 <= n\}$ isn't subgaussian. However, since this set is bounded, all the marginals $\langle X,x \rangle$ should be bounded, so shouldn't be $X$ subgaussian? In fact, by Cauchy-Schwartz, $||X||_{\psi_2}$ should be less than $\sup_{x \in K} ||x||_2$ if $K$ is bounded.

Where is my reasoning failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the latest version of the book (it's just on his website), he corrected this problem in the latest version. Now you are asked to *"Show that the subgaussian norm of this distribution is not bounded by an absolute constant as the dimension n grows."* There’s nothing wrong with this argument.

But what worth noticing is that you need to have a finer bound in the case where your bounds on 
$\langle X,x \rangle$ depends on $n$. Because the orcliz norm may not grow as the dimension $n$ and the size of convex body grows. Like the case when $X\sim \text{Unif}(\sqrt{n} S^{n-1})$, you need a better bound for it. But if you are only interested in Unif$(S^{n-1})$ (say), using the boundedness should be just fine.